# How add a padding to div without using css in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, border, padding, spacing

I am trying to add a padding-bottom to an div class="col-md-4" directly without using css. Is it possible?

I tried this code

```html
<div class="col-md-4 padding-bottom:15px">
```

also

```html
<div class="col-md-4" "padding-bottom:15px">
```

full content code is

```html
    <div class="gal">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="grid clearfix">
              @foreach($albums as $album)
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <figure class="effect-julia"> <img src="{{$album->gallery->imageUrl(null,300,239)}}" alt="czcsdcsd -{{$album->name}}"/>
                <figcaption>
                  <h2>{{$album->name}}</h2>
                  <div>
                    <p>View More</p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="{{url('gallery/'.$album->slug)}}" title="gsggss {{$album->name}}">View more</a> </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </div>
    @endforeach
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

it does not change anything.please help

Comment: Learn the difference between the [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) and [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) attributes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom:15px"></div>
```

Just use the attribute `style`, but I have to say using CSS in the HTML directly is not the best way...

Comment: @AnoopVijayan Sorry, try again without semicolon. I updated it

Comment: actually this did the trick   div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 15px"....thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use bs4 classes like `pb-number` for setting padding-bottom, or `pt-number` for setting padding-top where *number* is number from 0 to 5 (or auto) which is equivalent to values in `rem` from .25rem to 3rem.

In your case, you can use `class="pb-1"` for example.

You can find out more in the official [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) of bootstrap4:

Comment: can you please full code , in the documentation there is no example without css